bibliography separated using TexStudio
I m working on my thesis and trying to have seperated bibliographies for each chapter so my code goes as follows :
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter*{acknowledgments}
\include{chapter2}

\include{chapter3}

\end{document}

meanwhile on every chapter i have this :
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\scriptsize 
\bibliography{chapter2bib}

and i get a compile error that it didn't find the file please not that it was working on overleaf perfectly but for some reasons i couldn't use it anymore and now i want to use it on texstudio
Updated

here is the error code i get : This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX
24.4) The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux The style file: unsrtnat.bst Database file #1: chapter2bib.bib Warning--I didn't find
a database entry for "1" (There was 1 warning)





Please look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for help preparing a minimal example people can work with. Note that I deleted biber from the tags as you're not using it. Please provide the exact error message you get (copy-paste the text).

i have updated the post with the error message

That's not an error. It's a warning. You see to have cited the key 1 but there is no 1 in the bib file.

i have updated some screenshots so maybe you could have a better overall view

The screenshots say the same. There's no error but you have a citation which uses an entry with key 1 while there is no such entry in your .bib. This means the bibliography is empty and so there is no .bbl. It's presumably an error in your .tex file. Look for a command citing 1.

the citation is there .and the problem is solved just by changing the bibliography style and by changing bibtex to biber

Sorry, but you can't simply change the style and use biber because you can't use biber with \bibliographystyle or chapterbib. Please use the link I provided to prepare a minimal example which other people can compile to reproduce the problem. What you have shown is not an error but only a warning that you've cited something not found in the database. Since that entry isn't in code you've shared and since you've not shared code anybody else can use, it's hard to guess the problem.
